# Getting a different image to appear in a gui based on a random number generator

Tags: java, user-interface, imageicon, actionevent

I am very new to programming and I am totally lost on this homework assignment.  The assignment is to have a gui that displays two different dice.  When I click on the button the random number generator is supposed to have different images of the dice appear.  I can get my images to appear when I don't have any "if" statements so I know that the path is working.  When I add the "if" statements to assign the image for one of the dice I get an error that it cannot find symbol.  Since this worked when the icon was statically assigned I assume it is the "if" statement causing the problem but it may come back to the random number.  Please advise on what I am doing wrong.  The code attached only has the non-working code for the left die.

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        Random randomNumbers = new Random();  // Generates random numbers
        int valLeft;  // holds random number
        int valRight;  // holds random number

        // get values for the dice
        valLeft = randomNumbers.nextInt(6)+1; // range 1-6
        valRight = randomNumbers.nextInt(6)+1; // range 1-6

        // assign the image for the left die
        if (valLeft==1)
        {
            ImageIcon leftDie = new ImageIcon("Die1.png");
        }
         if (valLeft==2)
        {
            ImageIcon leftDie = new ImageIcon("Die2.png");
        }
          if (valLeft==3)
        {
            ImageIcon leftDie = new ImageIcon("Die3.png");
        }
           if (valLeft==4)
        {
            ImageIcon leftDie = new ImageIcon("Die4.png");
        }
            if (valLeft==5)
        {
            ImageIcon leftDie = new ImageIcon("Die5.png");
        }
             if (valLeft==6)
        {
            ImageIcon leftDie = new ImageIcon("Die6.png");
        }


        // put image on label
        imageLabelLeft.setIcon(leftDie);

        // assign the image for the right die
        ImageIcon rightDie = new ImageIcon("Die6.png");
        imageLabelRight.setIcon(rightDie);

        // remove the text from the labels
        imageLabelLeft.setText(null);
        imageLabelRight.setText(null);

        // repack the frame for the new images
        pack();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing scope issues, `leftDie` scope is restricted to if block only so, move the `ImageIcon leftDie ==` out of your `if` statements. Change this code:

```
    if (valLeft==1)
    {
        ImageIcon leftDie = new ImageIcon("Die1.png");
    }
```

To like this:

```
    ImageIcon leftDie = null;
    if (valLeft==1)
    {
        leftDie = new ImageIcon("Die1.png");
    }
```

This should work.